# iOS switch between two controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have two tab controllers on my delegate and I would like to switch them appear as needed. RootController is displayed as default and when I would like to display secondController from another class I use,

```
    myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.window addSubview:appDelegate.secondController.view];
    [appDelegate.rootController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

problem is when I am trying to go back using same method. Crashes due to bad acces exception...

```
  myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];   
    [appDelegate.window addSubview:appDelegate.rootController.view];
    [appDelegate.secondController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you have two tabbarcontrollars in your app ? .. or just one tabbarcontroller with two view controllers in it?

Comment: give your BOOL appdidFinishLaunching method code.. it should be in app delegate.m file

Comment: Apple wont accept an app which have two tab bars init, you are breaking APPLE'S Design rules and i appreciate apple for rejecting apps like that

Comment: @sree, my tabBars are never shown simultaneously! should be the same if you add or remove a tab programmatically so I do not really understand your criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not remove the rootController From Superview. Remove that line

```
[appDelegate.rootController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

and when you want to go back to your rootController just add the following lines:

```
myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.secondController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: thank you but same issue! I set an empty function on my delegate to test it and problem seems that come from a callback singleton not related to superview...

Comment: well, problem came from ARC. I set flags to disable it only in some classes so appDelegate doesn't need to be retained. Thank you for help